# Cannot add multiple streams derived from the same broadcast stream to a StreamController

Tags: dart

I am implementing one tokenizer. It parses the document, tokenizes it on a set of possible delimiters and then provides me combination of 1-, 2- and 3-word tokens.
I was able to achieve my goal, but only in one specific way:

```
  Stream<String> contentStr = file.openRead().transform(utf8.decoder);
  Stream<String> tokens = contentStr.transform(charSplitter).transform(tokenizer).asBroadcastStream();
  var twoWordTokens = tokens.transform(sliding(2));
  var threeWordTokens = tokens.transform(sliding(3));
  StreamController<String> merger = StreamController();
  tokens.forEach((token) => merger.add(token));
  threeWordTokens.forEach((token) => merger.add(token));
  twoWordTokens.forEach((token) => merger.add(token));
  merger.stream.forEach(print);
```

As you can see I do following:

- broadcast original stream of tokens
- transform it to 2 additional streams by sliding window transformation
- create a `StreamConsumer` (`StreamController` to be precise) and pump every event from 3 streams to that stream consumer.
- then I print every element of the stream consumer to test

It works but I don't like that I add each element from source streams via `StreamConsumer.add` method. I wanted to use `StreamController.addStream` instead but that somehow does not work.
The following code gives me a `Bad state: Cannot add event while adding a stream` error and I understand why:

```
  StreamController<String> merger = StreamController();
  merger.addStream(tokens);
  merger.addStream(twoWordTokens);
  merger.addStream(threeWordTokens);
  merger.stream.forEach(print);
```

This is per [API documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamController/addStream.html) of the `StreamController.addStream`.
So I need to wait for each `addStream` returning future completion:

```
StreamController<String> merger = StreamController();
await merger.addStream(tokens);
await merger.addStream(twoWordTokens);
await merger.addStream(threeWordTokens);
await merger.stream.forEach(print);
```

But in this case I get nothing printed in the console.

If I do this:

```
StreamController<String> merger = StreamController();
merger.stream.forEach(print);
await merger.addStream(tokens);
await merger.addStream(twoWordTokens);
await merger.addStream(threeWordTokens);
```

Then only the 1-word tokens, i.e. elements of the original broadcast stream are printed. Elements of the derived streams are not.

I kind of understand why this happens, because all my streams are derived from the original broadcast stream.

Is there a better way to implement such a pipeline?

Probably my problem can be reformulated in terms of stream duplication/forking, but I can't see a way to clone a stream in Dart. If you can advice on that - please do.

Comment: In you last example, could you try move "merger.stream.forEach(print);" to before the first addStream call and also make so the forEach call is not awaited. My theory is the addStream call are waiting for the events to be processed but since there are no listener on the stream, the call are just waiting forever.

Comment: I tried that before posting the question. It prints then all the 1-word tokens, and execution completes. So 2 other streams are not processed. I also kind of understand why, because first `await` then consumes the whole broadcast stream, but I am not sure I understand completely.
Also regarding `the call are just waiting forever` - in this case the execution should not complete with `Process finished with exit code 0` in the console, but it does so.

In general, looking at `StreamController.addStream` documentation it looks straitghforward but in reality I can't use it...

Comment: It will be awating forever ecause you actually never [close](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-async/StreamController/close.html) the tokens stream.
As stated in the `addStream` documentation: 
`Returns a future which completes when the source stream is done.`

Comment: @Mattia I've added one more line in the beginning:
`Stream<String> contentStr = file.openRead().transform(utf8.decoder);`.
So as you can see it all streams from the file initially. I thought that when the file gets read completely then the file stream will be done and then all derived streams as well automatically. Isn't it so?

Comment: Yeah, my bad, btw you could be able to use [mergeAll](https://pub.dev/documentation/stream_transform/latest/stream_transform/mergeAll.html) from [stream_transform](https://pub.dev/packages/stream_transform) as such:
`tokens.transform(mergeAll[stream1, stream2, ...]).listen(print)` never tried such a thing tough

Comment: Maybe broadcast stream gets not closed when underlying stream is done? And thanks for pointing the lib, will try later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope to allow concurrent `addStream` at some point, but until then, you need to handle the events indpendently:

```
var allAdds = [
    tokens.forEach(merger.add), 
    twoWordTokens.forEach(merger.add), 
    threeWordTokens.forEach(merger.add)]; 
Future.wait(allAdds).then((_) { merger.close(); });

merger.stream.forEach(print);
```

That's if you want to control everything yourself. You can also use the [`StreamGroup`](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamGroup-class.html) class from `package:async`. It collects a number of streams and emits their events as a single stream.

This assumes that you have no error events.

Comment: Looks good, but when I try to set a breakpoint on the line `merger.close();` it never reach there. Or if I add there some print statement it never prints anything. So I suspect the stream controller gets not actually closed. Any ideas why?

Comment: Sorry, I've found a bug in my code. In one of my transformers I forgot to close the inner stream controller. So everything is fine. Thanks for the `StreamGroup` reference.